# Javascript Regex to convert dot notation to bracket notation

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider this javascript:

```
var values = {
    name: "Joe Smith",
    location: {
        city: "Los Angeles",
        state: "California"
    }
}

var string = "{name} is currently in {location.city}, {location.state}";

var out = string.replace(/{([\w\.]+)}/g, function(wholematch,firstmatch) {
    return typeof values[firstmatch] !== 'undefined' ? 
        values[firstmatch] : wholematch;
});
```

This will output the following:

```
Joe Smith is currently in {location.city}, {location.state}
```

But I want to output the following:

```
Joe Smith is currently in Los Angeles, California
```

I'm looking for a good way to convert multiple levels of dot notation found between braces in the string into multiple parameters to be used with bracket notation, like this:

```
values[first][second][third][etc]
```

Essentially, for this example, I'm trying to figure out what regex string and function I would need to end up with the equivalent of:

```
out = values[name] + " is currently in " + values["location"]["city"] +
    values["location"]["state"];
```

**NOTE:** I'd like to do this without using `eval()`.

Comment: Just noticed a typo. Renamed `var joe` to `var values`

Comment: Another similar question has an alternative solution by @J-P to the answers here. It looks fairly elegant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344392/dynamic-deep-selection-for-a-javascript-object/3344487#3344487

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using a helper function to iteratively access the properties:

```
function getNestedValue(obj, prop) {
  var value, props = prop.split('.'); // split property names

  for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    if (typeof obj != "undefined") {
      obj = obj[props[i]]; // go next level
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

var string = "{name} is currently in {location.city}, {location.state}";

var out = string.replace(/{([^}]+)}/g, function(wholematch,firstmatch) {
  var value = getNestedValue(joe, firstmatch);
  return typeof value !== 'undefined' ? value : wholematch;
});
// "Joe Smith is currently in Los Angeles, California"
```

Try the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/epaqi4/edit).

**Edit**: Something slightly *elegant*, using the [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method, part of the new ECMAScript 5th Edition Standard:

```
function replace(str, obj) {
  return str.replace(/{([^}]+)}/g, function(wholematch,firstmatch) {
    var value = firstmatch.split('.').reduce(function (a, b) {
      return a[b];
    }, obj);
    return typeof value !== 'undefined' ? value : wholematch;
  });
}

replace("{name} is currently in {location.city}, {location.state}", values);
// "Joe Smith is currently in Los Angeles, California"
```

Try the new example [here](http://jsbin.com/iqoye/edit).

Comment: @CMS: nice, that works! However, it doesn't seem as elegant as a regex-based solution, and I'd like to believe there is a regex way to do it. Then again, maybe it would be a waste of time to pursue a regex solution.

Comment: @CMS: doesn't your regex allow anything between the braces? if i want to limit values to valid javascript variable names `[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]`, wouldn't it be best to use `/{([\w\.]+)}/g` ? Actually, that would allow a period at the beginning, which isn't allowed, but it's close. Oh yeah, I think I need to include `$` as well.

Comment: @Tauren, right it's a bit permissive, I didn't care too much, because when you access properties with the bracket notation (or use strings in an object literal), there are no restrictions, i.e. `obj["3.xx\u0009"]` ...

Comment: @CMS: very cool! too bad `reduce` isn't supported universally yet, but I guess `Array.prototype.reduce` isn't that big to include.

Comment: @Tauren, It isn't big, a standard compliant version is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility)... IE is the only major browser that lacks of this standard methods...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to integrate this in Javascript, but here's a Java snippet that uses regex to do the transformation you need:

```
    String[] tests = {
        "{name}",
        "{location.city}",
        "{location.state.zip.bleh}",
    };
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\\{?(\\w+).?", "[$1]"));
    }
```

This prints:

```
[name]
[location][city]
[location][state][zip][bleh]
```

Essentially it replaces all occurrences of `\{?(\w+).?` to `[$1]`.

Comment: hmm, interesting. However, even if I got this working in JS, I'm thinking I would end up with a string that I'd need to `eval`, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the topic [Error-free deep property access?](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_thread/thread/909ddea61f431a1a#) posted at comp.lang.javascript - this presents several approaches for doing what you want.

For the regexp, all you need is `/{.*?}/g`