# Assigning dynamic left-hand-side in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have the following array and object:

```
var arr = [['foo', 0],['bar'],['baz', 'qux']],
    arr2 = [3, 'quuuux', false],
    obj = {
        foo: [ 1, 2 ],
        bar: 'quux',
        baz: {
            quuux: true
        }
    };
```

I want to make these things happen dynamically by iterating through arr and arr2:

```
obj['foo'][0] = 3;
obj['bar'] = 'quuuux';
obj['baz']['qux'] = false;
```

Will there be any way to implement this without using eval()? Plus, is eval() evil even in this situation?

Edit:

1. The value of arr2 comes from user input, but this is just for an internal tool so the security issue is not very important.
2. The elements of arr might have arbitrary length, like

   obj['foo'][0]['bar'][2]['qux'] = 'quux';

should be available.

Comment: Where are the values being assigned coming from? If I'm reading your post correctly, this is easily possible without `eval`.

Comment: You going to need to explain *exactly* who is supposed to map to who here because it really isn't very clear.

Comment: @OneKitten I've edited the question a bit for better understanding.

Comment: Hint: `obj[ arr[i][0] ][ arr[i][1] ] = arr2[i];` in a loop, with some extra tests to allow for when `arr[i]` only has a single value. And no, `eval()` isn't evil, it's just almost always the wrong tool and you don't need it here. @MattBurland - Well it's not _very_ clear, but it's _reasonably_ clear.

Comment: Can you show us an example of how it would work with `eval`?

Comment: The value of arr2 comes from user input, but this is just for an internal tool so the security issue is not very important.

Comment: And the elements of arr might have arbitrary length, like
    obj['foo'][0]['bar'][2]['qux'] = 'quux';
should be available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic deep selection for a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344392/dynamic-deep-selection-for-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval()` isn't evil, it's just almost always the wrong tool and you don't need it here. Actually I'm not sure how it would help here anyway, given your input format.

A nested loop will do the trick for the input data you show:

```
var tmp, i, j;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    tmp = obj;
    for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length - 1; j++) // loop to second last item
        tmp = tmp[arr[i][j]];               // in sub array
    tmp[arr[i][j]] = arr2[i];
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/snmQ6/

Note that this will create new properties at the lowest level, e.g., the new `qux` property within `baz`, but it won't create new nested arrays/objects in your starting `obj`, it assumes they're already there and your `arr` input specifies appropriate index values to work a path to the lower level. I shall leave appropriate conditional logic to create nested objects as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: Beat me to it. :-) I was trying to work out how to know if a property was an object or array (number vs other), but if it's already there, there's no need to.

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot, but I already have the nested loop part as a separate function to query and read the data from an object. Is there any way to use the code as a separate function?

Comment: RobG - Yep, I decided to handle that by adding a disclaimer that I didn't handle that...

Comment: Hmm nevermind! Guess I have to implement getter and setter separately.

Comment: _"Is there any way to use the code as a separate function?"_ - Sure, wrap it in a function that takes in references to the object and the two arrays as arguments.